# Search bar remove some product in one specific search term Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

My problem concerns the search bar. I would like to know if it's possible not to display some product only on some search term (i don't want to disable search in product) ?

Example: We have the common word "échelle" when we do the search there is no "échelle", this is normal we don't have this product, but I have bedsheets with the word "échelle" in the title, I would like to remove them.

Thanks in advance for your help :)
Hugues

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution :-

Change product `Visibility` from Magento admin panel.

Admin -> Catalog -> Products
Edit the product and change product visibility from `Catalog,Search` to `Catalog`

[image]

Clear Magento cache

Comment: Hi, I don't want to disable the product like this, I want to remove the product from some specific words, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This configuration will fix your problem:

Change `product Visibility` from Magento admin panel.

`Admin -> Catalog -> Products` Edit the product and change product visibility from Catalog,Search to Catalog

[image]